# What is a containerized search?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

In MS Active Directory you can set an index for a so-called containerized search (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739174%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). But it is never explained what this acutally is …

There is a paragraph on [informit.com](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101405&seqNum=11) which does not sound clear at all. Is it meant to be special index just for an One-Level Scope LDAP search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this only work for one-level search scope.
The PI flag in the following link.

http://www.frickelsoft.net/blog/?p=151

Comment: Thank you, also for the useful link!